# unable to get test classes in jar file using maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

I have created cucumber test cases in my src/test/java folder with different packages and want to create a jar with all the dependencies and classes with maven. It compiles fine and runs well. However on converting into jar files, no classes/dependencies are present. Later I used maven shade plugin as below and still getting just a Meta-INF folder, and no classes anywhere. Using eclipse IDe and Maven 3.3.9, selenium 2.53.

After maven install got 2 jar files BsMonitor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT(got a lot of files but none of my class files) and original-BsMonitor-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT and both did not have the classes but just a META-INF Folder.

For shade plugin, under main class tag I have pointed it to the class that contains my Main method. I m not exactly sure if that's the way.

Also as seen in the image there are no files in src/Main/Java but only in src/test/java. How to proceed with this?

My project structure:

[image]

My POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>BsMonitor</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>BsMonitor</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jdom</groupId>
        <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
        <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>sonarlint-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.17</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.cucumber.Base.NewMain</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: You can remove the configuration from maven-surefire-plugin to include `**/*Test.java` cause this is default of [maven-surefire-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#includes). To define versions of plugins it should be done via pluginManagement. Is there any special reason why are you using such an older version of [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/)?

Answer (score 1):

Better to follow ways suggested by maven here is link hope this helps https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html

Comment: welcome and you should upvote to let others knows that it was useful

Comment: dont have enuf reputations to do so :(